# Python: Looping starts from final item and ends with the first one

Tags: python

Is there any "pythonic way" to  tell python to loop in a string (or list) starting from the last item and ending with the first one?

For example the word `Hans` i want python to read or sort it as `snaH`

Next, how can i tell pyhon the following: now from the string you resulted , search for 'a' find it ok , if you find 'n' follows 'a' , put '.' after 'n' and then print the original order of letters

Answer (score 8):

The clearest and most pythonic way to do this is to used the [`reversed()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reversed) builtin.

```
wrong_way = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for item in reversed(wrong_way):
    print(item)
```

Which gives:

```
4
3
2
1
```

This is the best solution as not only will it generate a reversed iterator naturally, but it can also call the dedicated `__reversed__()` method if it exists, allowing for a more efficient reversal in some objects.

You can use `wrong_way[::-1]` to reverse a list, but this is a lot less readable in code, and potentially less efficient. It does, however, show the power of list slicing.

Note that `reversed()` provide iterators, so if you want to do this with a string, you will need to convert your result back to a string, which is fortunately easy, as you just do:

```
"".join(iterator)
```

e.g:

```
"".join(reversed(word))
```

The [`str.join()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method takes an iterator and joins every element into a string, using the calling string as the separator, so here we use the empty string to place them back-to-back.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
>>> s = "Hans"
>>> for c in s[::-1]:
        print c

s
n
a
H
```

Alternatively, if you want a new string that's the reverse of the first, try this:

```
>>> "".join(reversed("Hans"))
'snaH'
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just use list_name[::-1]. e.g.

```
>>> l = ['one', 'two', 'three']
>>> for i in l[::-1]:
...   print i
... 
three
two
one
```